# asp.net core web application (.net framework) Failed to make the following project runnable: EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll' is denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core

I have an asp.net mvc 5 application that references various other projects which read and write to a database using Entity Framework 6. I added a new ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) and it compiles fine. If I add a reference to my domain project it compiles fine. However, when I create an instance of a class from my domain project inside the home controller in the asp.net core project, I get the following compiling error:

**Failed to make the following project runnable: (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1) reason: Access to the path bin\Debug\net461\win7-x64\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll' is denied.**

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: I get a similar error when trying to reference a .net 4.6.1 C# project from a .NET core project